# facebook side pane navigation

Tags: jquery

how is the main div content of the facebook home page changed when the user clicks on the links in the navigation pane? any ideas on how to achieve this using jquery?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery, you could easily use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) to use ajax to load markup from the appropriate URL (specified by which nav link was clicked) into the "main div content" area that you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look up a technique called AJAX (assuming you're not able to preload all the content.

Answer (score 1):

It is AJAX.

> XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is an API available in web browser scripting languages such as JavaScript. It is used to send HTTP or HTTPS requests directly to a web server and load the server response data directly back into the script.

[XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

jQuery can indeed do this.

```
$('#main-content').load('http://example.com/get-status');
```

The example above is simplified. Depending on what your requirements were, the code could (and most probably will) look different.